# Mesh won't respond to rigged armature with automatic weights

Tags: rigging, armature, pose-mode

This is my first wire mesh/blender project and I've hit a real road block trying to rig my model. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've followed this tutorial series on rigging: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1vhlTGP1-o&list=PLZpDYt0cyiuu-sxJKbuYh8OjtgmXNacCV&index=2

After pairing my armature with my mesh using the automatic weights setting (ctrl P/cmd P mac) the mesh won't respond to any movement of the armature in pose mode. The armature moves freely but the mesh doesn't follow the movement.

Armature appears in the object's modifiers tab.

In weight painting mode the entire mesh is blue not red so nothing seems connected.

I've checked parenting of all bones in the armature to make sure it is working fine and tested movement of the armature.

I've checked that the mesh is parented to the armature (not the other way round)

The mesh was made from separate objects joined together to make one single object, I don't know if this is the cause of the problem.[image]

I've added a screen shot which might show someone something I am missing, and here is a link to my blender file if anyone has the time and would like to help out to help https://transfernow.net/427qb1w9c3g6

Thanks all

Comment: did you select the mesh, **then the bone** and press ctrl p etc.?  (that's how your supposed to do it)

Comment: by the way, who is the guy your rigging?

Comment: That file is a crazy-big 165MB so I'll watch from here. From Weight Paint Mode, can you see the weight of different bones? That could verify their correct attachment too.

Comment: You probably had the bone heat error.  in that case, the rig doesn't know how to parent, sometimes caused by overlapping vertices.

Comment: I selected the mesh, then the bone in the layers panel and pressed cmd P (mac). I also have tried to select them in the same order in the view port by clicking the mesh and then on any bone. It's a ninja, loosely based on death stroke with a bit of snake eye from GI joe thrown in there.

Comment: @HelloHiHola in weight paint mode the whole mesh is just blue, so I don't think it is attached, I've taken a screen shot here ![Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/SnjiS3K.png).

Comment: I didn't see an error when I did it, I unparented the mesh by pressing alt P and clear parents and repeated the process to see if an error would come up but didn't get anything. If overlapping vertices is the issue how would I test this/is there a clean up process I can do?

Comment: I've attempted to fix the overlapping vertices issue.. I'm using 2.8 and have removed doubles by going in to mesh> clean up> merge by distance. I then tried to pair the mesh and armature again but it didn't work.